# Export a CSV from Azure Automation to Microsoft Teams instead of blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-automation

I am attempting to run a daily report with Azure Automation that will produce a CSV. Per Microsoft's documentation this report can be exported to Azure blob storage. However I was curious if it is possible to skip that and export it straight to Microsoft Teams. Per some articles I am reading it is possible, but nobody provides a complete set of instructions.

Would anyone be able to help point me in the right direction for this?

Comment: MS Teams stores attachments in one drive. So 1) using Microsoft graph You can upload csv in one drive. 2) using the Microsoft graph send a message(with the link of csv) to teams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to send the csv file to OneDrive or SharePoint site.

You can send the link of the OneDrive or SharePoint link to teams via below commands/process, and I followed [Microsoft-Document-1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3) and [Microsoft-Document-2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook):

Secondly, I opened my Teams Channel and right click on channel and the clicked-on Connectors as below:

[image]

Then you need to add Incoming Webhook:
[image]

Then Click on Configure Incoming Webhook **Configure** and the type the necessary fields and then click on **create**.
Then copy the url of webhook and paste in `$myTeamsWebHook` below commands:

```
$myTeamsWebHook = "https://microsoft.webhook.office.com/webhookb2/0a2b3bc0-fb46-4401-ad40-51b19omingWebhook/6493f5388bffd69184/c977856c-f4bf-449d8"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -ContentType 'Application/Json'  -Body '{"text":"https://ms.portal.azure.com/#home"}' -Uri $myTeamsWebHook
```

Output:

Now link has been delivered as message in Teams:

[image]

As an `example` I am sharing `azure portal link`, there you can share your `Onedrive or sharepoint link`.

What I usually follow is sending to Storage Account then getting it from there to teams.