# Permission for Teams Messages out of a Power Automate Flow

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, power-automate

im trying to send a simple message to a Teams Chat after a trigger in Power Automate. But i get the follwoing Error-Message.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BotRequestFailed",
    "message": "Fehler bei Bot Framework-Anforderung: „{\"error\":{\"code\":\"BotDisabledByAdmin\",\"message\":\"The tenant admin disabled this bot\"}}“."
  }
}
```

Simple enough, I understand that I have to change some permission. Can anyone tell me exactly which permission I have to adapt so that the Flow is able to send a chat?

Thanks!

Comment: To enable the bot, follow these steps:
1. Make sure you have the necessary permissions to manage apps in your Microsoft 365 tenant. 2. Go to the Microsoft Teams admin center (https://admin.teams.microsoft.com). 3. In the left navigation pane, click on "Teams apps" and then select "Permission policies". 4. Select the permission policy that applies to the users who will be using the bot. 5. In the "Bots" section, make sure the "Allow sideloading of external bots" option is enabled. 6. Save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

> im trying to send a simple message to a Teams Chat after a trigger in Power Automate.

I do not use bot, alternatively I send messages to teams by using **`incoming webhook`** of teams. To create incoming webhook follow this [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75155642/17623802) or:

Firstly, click on teams channel and  then click on mage channel, then on edit connectors then configure incoming webhook :

[image]

Below is the **`design`** using which I send messages to teams:

[image]

Body should be like  `{"text":"Hello Team, This Message is from Rithwik Bojja."}`

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`In Teams:`**

[image]