# How to format an Azure Logic App JSON payload containing a Teams message with Azure Alert?

Tags: json, azure, microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, azure-alerts

I've been trying to configure Azure Alerts (specifically VM low disk space query) to send a message to a Teams channel every time an alert is triggered using an Azure Logic App. It does what it's supposed to, however I do not know how to format the message to make it look a bit more neat.
What I'm currently getting is this:
[Teams message I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne9Cc.png)

I'd like it to also contain the drive and value  (which the email alerts triggered by the same query do). I am using the built-in Logic App Teams integration (*Post message in a chat or channel*). Currently just configured to return the configurationItems value which sadly, is the closest I got to what I want to achieve, anything else displays an absolute mess of JSON code.
[Logic App Designer view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dg9f.png)

I've tried different combination of values and variables but the app designer is very limited in what it allows me to do. The query I'm using is:

```
InsightsMetrics 
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk" 
| where Name == "FreeSpacePercentage" 
| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"]) 
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Disk, Computer 
| project Computer, Disk, Val | where Val < 10
```

The data I want to 'extract' is stored in the *Computer*, *Disk* and *Val* dimensions.
Below is the JSON output payload from the logic app, as you can see all the data I need to extract is stored in the dimensions stored above.

```
{
    "headers": {
        "Expect": "100-continue",
        "Host": "prod-29.uksouth.logic.azure.com",
        "Max-Forwards": "10",
        "User-Agent": "IcMBroadcaster/1.0",
        "X-CorrelationContext": "RkkKACgAAAACAAAAEACyLD23wrGCS7pV2gtMjiR5AQAQAIpdK63VFIhCsQq3AI7HA4c=",
        "X-ARR-LOG-ID": "32bea9c0-3db3-4cee-95c1-2b7f0d1e1f0f",
        "CLIENT-IP": "52.184.145.166:31132",
        "DISGUISED-HOST": "prod-29.uksouth.logic.azure.com",
        "X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID": "flowfe-prod-ln-rp00-app",
        "WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME": "flowfe-prod-ln-rp00-app.flow-prod-ln-rp00-ase.p.azurewebsites.net",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "X-AppService-Proto": "https",
        "X-ARR-SSL": "2048|256|CN=Microsoft Azure RSA TLS Issuing CA 03, O=Microsoft Corporation, C=US|CN=uksouth.logic.azure.com, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US",
        "X-Forwarded-TlsVersion": "1.2",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "52.184.145.166:31132",
        "X-Original-URL": "/workflows/ce0dd9c044ab4ebe8bb5d76381be9765/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=SCgN-yEDezdc7OmH7v_IQwM3M4KUIjM8qNSciI7SMXo",
        "X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL": "/workflows/ce0dd9c044ab4ebe8bb5d76381be9765/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=SCgN-yEDezdc7OmH7v_IQwM3M4KUIjM8qNSciI7SMXo",
        "Content-Length": "4731",
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "body": {
        "schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
        "data": {
            "essentials": {
                "alertId": "/subscriptions/69d11cc8-b7af-4c8c-bb54-9cf72cabbcba/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/bbf927f7-de30-b602-1c83-1775e44f0017",
                "alertRule": "VM_LowDiskSpace",
                "severity": "Sev3",
                "signalType": "Log",
                "monitorCondition": "Fired",
                "monitoringService": "Log Alerts V2",
                "alertTargetIDs": [
                    "/subscriptions/69d11cc8-b7af-4c8c-bb54-9cf72cabbcba/resourcegroups/gds-uks-svr-mgmt-rg/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/gds-uks-svr-mgmt-law"
                ],
                "configurationItems": [
                    "GDS-SCCM-VM01"
                ],
                "originAlertId": "7eab1d19-63bd-4690-9cac-a1e9eb843efd",
                "firedDateTime": "2024-03-03T10:49:56.8527969Z",
                "description": "This will send and alert if any VM's disk space is less than 10%.",
                "essentialsVersion": "1.0",
                "alertContextVersion": "1.0"
            },
            "alertContext": {
                "properties": {},
                "conditionType": "LogQueryCriteria",
                "condition": {
                    "windowSize": "P1D",
                    "allOf": [
                        {
                            "searchQuery": "InsightsMetrics\n| where Namespace == \"LogicalDisk\"\n| where Name == \"FreeSpacePercentage\"\n| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)[\"vm.azm.ms/mountId\"])\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Disk, Computer\n| project Computer, Disk, Val\n| where Val < 10\n",
                            "metricMeasureColumn": null,
                            "targetResourceTypes": "['Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces']",
                            "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
                            "threshold": "1",
                            "timeAggregation": "Count",
                            "dimensions": [
                                {
                                    "name": "Computer",
                                    "value": "GDS-SCCM-VM01"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Disk",
                                    "value": "L:"
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "Val",
                                    "value": "9.17095184326172"
                                }
                            ],
                            "metricValue": 1,
                            "failingPeriods": {
                                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1,
                                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1
                            },
                            "linkToSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.com#@6ebe178c-d0e7...
                            "linkToFilteredSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.com#@6ebe178c..
                            "linkToSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspa...
                            "linkToFilteredSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1...
                            "event": null
                        }
                    ],
                    "windowStartTime": "2024-03-02T10:46:51Z",
                    "windowEndTime": "2024-03-03T10:46:51Z"
                }
            },
            "customProperties": {}
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the Logic App Code View, I am quite sure that I can achieve my goal by manually editing the 'messageBody' part, but I am not sure what needs changing:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Post_message_in_a_chat_or_channel": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "messageBody": "<p>@{triggerBody()?['data']?['essentials']?['configurationItems']}</p>",
                        "recipient": {
                            "channelId": "19:d95313643c10419690663a2d1a026c7a@thread.skype",
                            "groupId": "e0112486-b573-4377-b8a9-df4450dd4383"
                        }
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['teams_2']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/beta/teams/conversation/message/poster/@{encodeURIComponent('User')}/location/@{encodeURIComponent('Channel')}"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "data": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "alertContext": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "condition": {
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "allOf": {
                                                        "items": {
                                                            "properties": {
                                                                "dimensions": {
                                                                    "items": {
                                                                        "properties": {
                                                                            "name": {
                                                                                "type": "string"
                                                                            },
                                                                            "value": {
                                                                                "type": "string"
                                                                            }
                                                                        },
                                                                        "required": [
                                                                            "name",
                                                                            "value"
                                                                        ],
                                                                        "type": "object"
                                                                    },
                                                                    "type": "array"
                                                                },
                                                                "metricName": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                },
                                                                "metricNamespace": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                },
                                                                "metricValue": {
                                                                    "type": "number"
                                                                },
                                                                "operator": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                },
                                                                "threshold": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                },
                                                                "timeAggregation": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "required": [
                                                                "metricName",
                                                                "metricNamespace",
                                                                "operator",
                                                                "threshold",
                                                                "timeAggregation",
                                                                "dimensions",
                                                                "metricValue"
                                                            ],
                                                            "type": "object"
                                                        },
                                                        "type": "array"
                                                    },
                                                    "windowSize": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "type": "object"
                                            },
                                            "conditionType": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "properties": {}
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "customProperties": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "Key1": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "Key2": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    },
                                    "essentials": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "alertContextVersion": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "alertId": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "alertRule": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "alertTargetIDs": {
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": "array"
                                            },
                                            "configurationItems": {
                                                "items": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": "array"
                                            },
                                            "description": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "essentialsVersion": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "firedDateTime": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "monitorCondition": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "monitoringService": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "originAlertId": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "resolvedDateTime": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "severity": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            },
                                            "signalType": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "type": "object"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "schemaId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "teams_2": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/69d11cc8-b7af-4c8c-bb54-9cf72cabbcba/resourceGroups/GDS-UKS-Prod-LogicApps-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/teams-1",
                    "connectionName": "teams-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/69d11cc8-b7af-4c8c-bb54-9cf72cabbcba/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/uksouth/managedApis/teams"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How do I modify this app to send a nice and neat message to our Teams channel, displaying the alert with Computer name, disk and value? I was thinking about using IncomingWebhook integration instead but I am not sure how to configure it. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

I tried modifying the values within the App Designer but it ended up displaying a mess of incomprehensible code in the message. Clicking the *dimensions* value within app designer automatically puts in in the *foreach* loop which kinda makes sense as there are multiple dimensions but I do not know how to extract the desired values from the payload. I am using the Azure Common Alerts Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I modify this app to send a nice and neat message to our Teams channel, displaying the alert with Computer name, disk and value? I was thinking about using IncomingWebhook integration instead but I am not sure how to configure it. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Firstly created a incoming webhook like below:

[image]

**`Design`**:

[image]

Then:

[image]

**body:**

```
{"text":@{body('Create_HTML_table')}}
```

**`Output:`**
[image]

[image]

**`Parse Json schema:`**

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "alertContext": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "condition": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {
                                        "allOf": {
                                            "type": "array",
                                            "items": {
                                                "type": "object",
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "dimensions": {
                                                        "type": "array",
                                                        "items": {
                                                            "type": "object",
                                                            "properties": {
                                                                "name": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                },
                                                                "value": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "required": [
                                                                "name",
                                                                "value"
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "event": {},
                                                    "failingPeriods": {
                                                        "type": "object",
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": {
                                                                "type": "integer"
                                                            },
                                                            "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": {
                                                                "type": "integer"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "linkToFilteredSearchResultsAPI": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "linkToFilteredSearchResultsUI": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "linkToSearchResultsAPI": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "linkToSearchResultsUI": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "metricMeasureColumn": {},
                                                    "metricValue": {
                                                        "type": "integer"
                                                    },
                                                    "operator": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "searchQuery": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "targetResourceTypes": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "threshold": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    },
                                                    "timeAggregation": {
                                                        "type": "string"
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "required": [
                                                    "dimensions",
                                                    "event",
                                                    "failingPeriods",
                                                    "linkToFilteredSearchResultsAPI",
                                                    "linkToFilteredSearchResultsUI",
                                                    "linkToSearchResultsAPI",
                                                    "linkToSearchResultsUI",
                                                    "metricMeasureColumn",
                                                    "metricValue",
                                                    "operator",
                                                    "searchQuery",
                                                    "targetResourceTypes",
                                                    "threshold",
                                                    "timeAggregation"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "windowEndTime": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "windowSize": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        "windowStartTime": {
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "conditionType": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "properties": {
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "properties": {}
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "customProperties": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {}
                        },
                        "essentials": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "alertContextVersion": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "alertId": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "alertRule": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "alertTargetIDs": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "configurationItems": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "description": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "essentialsVersion": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "firedDateTime": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "monitorCondition": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "monitoringService": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "originAlertId": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "severity": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "signalType": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "schemaId": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "CLIENT-IP": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Content-Length": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Content-Type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "DISGUISED-HOST": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Expect": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Host": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Max-Forwards": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "User-Agent": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-ARR-LOG-ID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-ARR-SSL": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-AppService-Proto": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-CorrelationContext": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-Forwarded-For": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-Forwarded-Proto": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-Forwarded-TlsVersion": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-Original-URL": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also refer [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77872252/17623802).

**Edit:**

Input Payload:

````
{
  "body": {
    "data": {
      "alertContext": {
        "condition": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "dimensions": [
                {
                  "name": "Computer",
                  "value": "GDS-SCCM-VM01"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Disk",
                  "value": "L:"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Val",
                  "value": "9.17095184326172"
                }
              ],
              "event": null,
              "failingPeriods": {
                "minFailingPeriodsToAlert": 1,
                "numberOfEvaluationPeriods": 1
              },
              "linkToFilteredSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1...",
              "linkToFilteredSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.com#@6ebe178c..",
              "linkToSearchResultsAPI": "https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspa...",
              "linkToSearchResultsUI": "https://portal.azure.com#@6ebe178c-d0e7...",
              "metricMeasureColumn": null,
              "metricValue": 1,
              "operator": "GreaterThanOrEqual",
              "searchQuery": "InsightsMetrics\n| where Namespace == \"LogicalDisk\"\n| where Name == \"FreeSpacePercentage\"\n| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)[\"vm.azm.ms/mountId\"])\n| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Disk, Computer\n| project Computer, Disk, Val\n| where Val < 10\n",
              "targetResourceTypes": "['Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces']",
              "threshold": "1",
              "timeAggregation": "Count"
            }
          ],
          "windowEndTime": "2024-03-03T10:46:51Z",
          "windowSize": "P1D",
          "windowStartTime": "2024-03-02T10:46:51Z"
        },
        "conditionType": "LogQueryCriteria",
        "properties": {}
      },
      "customProperties": {},
      "essentials": {
        "alertContextVersion": "1.0",
        "alertId": "/subscriptions/69d11cc8-b7af-4c8c-bb54-9cf72cabbcba/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/bbf927f7-de30-b602-1c83-1775e44f0017",
        "alertRule": "VM_LowDiskSpace",
        "alertTargetIDs": [
          "/subscriptions/69d11cc8-b7af-4c8c-bb54-9cf72cabbcba/resourcegroups/gds-uks-svr-mgmt-rg/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/gds-uks-svr-mgmt-law"
        ],
        "configurationItems": [
          "GDS-SCCM-VM01"
        ],
        "description": "This will send and alert if any VM's disk space is less than 10%.",
        "essentialsVersion": "1.0",
        "firedDateTime": "2024-03-03T10:49:56.8527969Z",
        "monitorCondition": "Fired",
        "monitoringService": "Log Alerts V2",
        "originAlertId": "7eab1d19-63bd-4690-9cac-a1e9eb843efd",
        "severity": "Sev3",
        "signalType": "Log"
      }
    },
    "schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema"
  },
  "headers": {
    "CLIENT-IP": "52.184.145.166:31132",
    "Content-Length": "4731",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "DISGUISED-HOST": "prod-29.uksouth.logic.azure.com",
    "Expect": "100-continue",
    "Host": "prod-29.uksouth.logic.azure.com",
    "Max-Forwards": "10",
    "User-Agent": "IcMBroadcaster/1.0",
    "WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME": "flowfe-prod-ln-rp00-app.flow-prod-ln-rp00-ase.p.azurewebsites.net",
    "X-ARR-LOG-ID": "32bea9c0-3db3-4cee-95c1-2b7f0d1e1f0f",
    "X-ARR-SSL": "2048|256|CN=Microsoft Azure RSA TLS Issuing CA 03, O=Microsoft Corporation, C=US|CN=uksouth.logic.azure.com, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US",
    "X-AppService-Proto": "https",
    "X-CorrelationContext": "RkkKACgAAAACAAAAEACyLD23wrGCS7pV2gtMjiR5AQAQAIpdK63VFIhCsQq3AI7HA4c=",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "52.184.145.166:31132",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
    "X-Forwarded-TlsVersion": "1.2",
    "X-Original-URL": "/workflows/ce0dd9c044ab4ebe8bb5d76381be9765/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=SCgN-yEDezdc7OmH7v_IQwM3M4KUIjM8qNSciI7SMXo",
    "X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID": "flowfe-prod-ln-rp00-app",
    "X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL": "/workflows/ce0dd9c044ab4ebe8bb5d76381be9765/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=SCgN-yEDezdc7OmH7v_IQwM3M4KUIjM8qNSciI7SMXo"
  }
}```
````

Comment: Hi RithwikBojja,

thank you for taking the time to answer and explain this in great detail.
I have one question - in the 'Compose' step I'm asked to define Inputs ('Inputs' is required.) - what should I select as my inputs?

Comment: In compose action i have given json payload that you have given in question

Comment: I've selected 'allOf' as the input but now I'm getting the below error on the Parse JSON step:

'
[
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Object but got Array.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "",
    "schemaId": "#",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  }
]
'

Comment: @NaveenSharma Thanks for the reminder, I will accept the solution as soon as the problem is solved.

Comment: You will not get if you use rightly ```body('Parse_JSON')?['body']?['data']?['alertContext']?['condition']?['allOf']``` as i have got the answer

Comment: @RithwikBojja If I understand correctly, you pasted my raw payload into the inputs steps, right? What do I have use as the Compose input if I want this to automatically use the payload received from triggered alert?

Comment: Edited my answer (Edit section input payload) with payload of yours

Comment: I got that but what do I need to do for the process to be fully automated? I don't want to be pasting the payload into input manually each time.

Comment: You can use the httptrigger body as input https://i.imgur.com/ifI0RVm.png